# Update model field after some period in Django

Tags: python, django, model

I want automatically update field status in my model after 14 days.
Here is my model. I want to change **status_of_renting** to 0 after 15 days from **date_of_rental** (if date.today() if greater than date_of_return)

```
class RentCar(models.Model):
    NORMAL = 1
    PENALTY = 0 

    STATUS = (
        (NORMAL, 'All is fine'),
        (PENALTY, 'Penalty for using car')
    )

    car = models.ForeignKey('Car', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'car')
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'client')
    date_of_rental = models.DateField(blank= True, default=timezone.now)
    date_of_return = models.DateField(blank= True, default=date.today() + timedelta(days=14))
    status_of_renting = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS, default = 1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rental} - {self.car} / {self.client.fullname}'
```

I can override **def get_queryset()** or **dispatch** in my generics.ListView, but I*m sure it's terrible decision. Is there some better solution to change the status in field **status_of_renting**.

**views.py**

```
class RentCatView(ListView):
    model = RentCar

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.model.objects.filter(Q(status_of_renting = 1)&Q(date_of_return__lte = date.today())).update(status_of_renting=0)
        return self.model.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to update database in queryset is indeed bad idea - it will execute every time someone try to fetch list of `RentCar` which will pollute your database with requests.

You need to setup cron job to run your query to update `RentCar`. Good thing is that you can run it only once a day, since it is only time that `status_of_renting` should be changed.

You can use one of django app, such as [django-cron](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) or [django-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

For example, this is what you need to do with django-background-tasks:

```py
from background_task import background
from .models import RentCar

@background(schedule=24*60*60)
def update_status_of_renting(user_id):
    RentCar.objects.filter(Q(status_of_renting = 1)&Q(date_of_return__lte = date.today())).update(status_of_renting=0)
```

Comment: you need cron in order to run background-tasks